# Install Windows 10 on MacBook Pro (2008) with Linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot, installation, macbook

I've got a `MacBook Pro (2008)` with `Linux` installed as the only OS. Now I want to switch to `Windows 10`.

But when I'm choosing the USB with the `Windows 10 ISO` as the bootable drive, the computer just freezes and doesn't do anything, so I need to shut it down using a button. I've tried to format the disk using different file systems (like *FAT32, exFAT* and *NTFS*) and then install an `ISO` file there, but nothing worked. Also, I've tried to install `grub` for the double boot, so I could somehow install `Windows 10` and then delete `Linux`, but there is an error saying that the computer is running in the bios mode (but must in the UEFI).

How can I install Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues -

1. Macs don't have a BIOS, nor do they have UEFI, only EFI.
   Windows install on older Macs is done by using a protected MBR… & I honestly don't know how to make one of those without macOS installed, [though someone else might].
2. Win10 is not supported on an 08 Mac [nor Win8 for that matter], so there are no drivers for the hardware.
3. Getting an '08 to boot to anything from a USB stick is very hit & miss, it wasn't fully supported until '09 models. Closest you can get is to install Win7 [from a CD, not USB stick] & see if you can get the in-place update to work…

& a late 4…

4. When you say "Windows 10 ISO" do you in fact mean a proper installer made using Windows Media Creator, or do you literally mean an ISO file written to a USB stick? The latter won't boot even a PC.

Comment: Firstly I was using the Windows Media Creator tool to make a bootable disk, but when I realized it doesn't work I followed the tutorial to make the bootable disk using Linux.

But, as I understood, I almost have no chances to install Windows on this PC, because the CD-ROM doesn't work on this computer either.

Comment: You could test whether it will boot at all from USB by getting hold of a bootable macOS installer. El Capitan, 10.11 would be your best bet.

Comment: Nothing worked, but okay. 

Anyway, thank you for your help.